# Thickness of aluminium on Alcoa type forged aluminium wheels.

Tags: wheels, tractor, aluminum

Is there a good estimate of the thickness of the aluminium on Alcoa forged aluminium semi wheels 22.5 type. Figures need not be precise, or just a range, for 
estimates, is 1/2 an inch a good estimate for the thickness of the metal on an Alcoa type forged aluminium wheel? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Whereabouts are you taking the measurements? Hub face, rim, spokes...

Comment: As they have a kind of taper to the aluminium plate, ie the pictures show they have a different thickness from the part near the wheel rim to the part where near the bolt area. So, any info about thickness  near the Bolt area to near the rim is helpful! I could  then average the two get a kind of estimate! Or just any estimate of thickness whether near bolt area, or Rim!

Comment: Could you provide a picture?

Answer (score 2):

A standard 22.5" x 8.25" Alcoa wheel (p/n 88367x) has a disc thickness of .875" which is about double the thickness of a steel wheel.

You can find this and more information here https://buytruckwheels.com/22-5x8-25-hub-piloted-alcoa-wheel-lvl-one-finish.html

**full disclosure I work for buytruckwheels.com

Comment: Are you linked to this website in any way? If you are, you must disclose that in your answer, otherwise it will be flagged as spam. Please read [How not to be a spammer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)